# Comparing 2 one dimensional signals

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I have the following problem: I have 2 signals over time. They are from the same source so they should be the same. I want to check if they really are.

Complications:

- they may be measured with different sample rates
- the start / end time do not correlate. The measurement does not start at the same time and end at the same time.
- there may be an time offset between the two signals.

My thoughts go along Fourier transformation, convolution and statistical methods for comparison. Can someone post me some links where I can find more information on how to handle this?

Comment: Do you know the sampling rate for each signal?

Comment: yes I do. But it could occur that the sampling rate is not constant. Restriction to constant sampling rate signals may be an option if this reduces the complexity of the solution significantly.

Comment: Are these two waveforms exactely the same or just from the same source. For example if you have two versions of the same wavefile, which only differ by the sampling rate and offset, the problem is easier. If you have two recordings from the same source (for example two recordings of the same trombone playing the same melody, but recorded with different equipment) the problem get's much harder.

Comment: normally it's not an audio signal. It can be a digital value but it can also be an analog value. Sometimes they are actually from the same source and you want to check whether your measuring equipment is ok, sometimes it's from 2 different source that should act equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily correct for the phase by just shifting them so their centers of mass line up.  (Or alternatively, in the Fourier domain just multiplying by the inverse of the phase of the first coefficient.)

Similarly, if you want to line up the images given only partial data, you can just cross correlate and take the maximal value (which is again easy to do in the Fourier domain).

That leaves the only tricky part of this process as dealing with the sampling rates.  Now if you know a-priori what the sample rates are, (and if they are related by a rational number), you can just use sinc interpolation/downsampling to rescale them to a common sampling rate:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Bandlimited_Interpolation_Time_Limited_Signals.html

If you don't know the sampling rate, you may be a bit screwed.  Technically, you can try just brute forcing over all the different rescalings of your signal, but doing this tends to be either slow or else give mediocre results.

As a last suggestion, if you just want to match sounds exactly you can try using the cepstrum and verifying that the peaks of the signal are close enough to within some tolerance.  This type of analysis is used a lot in sound and speech recognition, with some refinements to make it operate a bit more locally.  It tends to work best with frequency modulated data like speech and music:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum

Answer (score 3):

Fourier transformation does sound like the right way.

There is too much mathematical information for me to just start explaining here so if you really wanna know what's going on with that (cause I don't think you can just use FT without understanding it) you should use this reference from MIT OpenCourseWare: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-103-fourier-analysis-theory-and-applications-spring-2004/lecture-notes/

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are working with a linux box and the waveforms that need to be processed have already been recorded, you can try to use the `file` command to display details about the recording. It gives you the sampling rate when it is invoked on a wav file, though I am not sure what format you are recording in.
2. If the signals are time-shifted with respect to each other, you may try to convolve one with a delta function with increasing delays and then comparing. On MATLAB, `conv` and `all` should be good enough.

These are just 'crude' attempts (almost like hacking at the problem). There may be algorithms that are shift-invariant that may do a better job.

Hope that helps.